# Moved Xcode project has missing files from other libraries

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I moved the folder of a project in Xcode to another computer, and I"m having some issues. I'm using `NMSSH` framework, and the `libz.dylib` file is missing from the project, and I'm unable to locate it, since the Inspector button for it is grayed out. The file is not on my system either. Shouldn't it have been inside my project folder?

Also, I'm using `MBProgressHUD`, and I'm using it by dragging its Xcode project in, and setting the appropriate links. One of the libraries `libMBProgressHUD.a` is missing, and I can't locate that either.

Everything was working fine on my other computer, so I'm guessing there's a problem with search paths, etc? Any help would be much appreciated. The errors are as follows:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/ramesh/Documents/CodeDump_Temp/iOS/RasbPiController/../../.Trash'


Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NMSSHSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in UserPi.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I would think that when you copy a folder from one PC to another you're only going to get the files in that folder.  Stuff in other folders will not automatically come along for the ride.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you can download the missing file from the link below**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/au2irnctslcpjih/libz.dylib

**and paste it in your iOS Simulator folder.  I hope it will work .**